# why kafka php consumer code running infinite

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I am using  [arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka) as kafka PHP client. I installed kafka client with PECL. I am using the following code for consuming data.

```
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('group.id', 'myConsumerGroup');
$rk = new RdKafka\Consumer($conf);
$rk->addBrokers("127.0.0.1");
$topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();
$topicConf->set('auto.commit.interval.ms', 100);
$topicConf->set('offset.store.method', 'broker');
$topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'earliest');
$topic = $rk->newTopic("test", $topicConf);
$topic->consumeStart(0, RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED);
while (true) {
    $message = $topic->consume(0, 120*10000);
    switch ($message->err) {
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
            var_dump($message);
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
            echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
            echo "Timed out\n";
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception($message->errstr(), $message->err);
            break;
    }
}
```

Even I changed while loop to for loop till 2 indexes like following but still same issue persists.

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    
}
```

I enabled port 9092 in Apache /etc/apache2/ports.conf by adding the following line in it

> Listen 9092

I am not getting what causing it to run infinitely?

Comment: Kafka doesn't use /etc/apache2, what do you mean "enabled"?

Comment: You're running the loop while true, and the only time it would break out of it would be when you throw the exception. All of the breaks are for the switch statement only. When you're using the for loop instead, try adding some logging for debugging, so you can see the steps of the process.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was supposing that, kafka uses 9092 so I activated Port 9092 from Apache

Comment: @aynber this line $message = $topic->consume(0, 120*10000); is taking time, I changed 120 to 1 and print_r($message->err) then got error "Trying to get property 'err' of non-object" and If I only print_r($message) then empty response

Comment: Kafka does use port 9092, but that's defined in `server.properties`, which you needed to start the broker and the correct property is `listeners`. I only say this because trying to connect to **Apache httpd server** with a Kafka consumer will not work. Also, if Kafka was already running, then you would expect a bind error when trying to start httpd service with your config here. Besides this, `addBrokers` should probably include the port no?

Comment: Regarding "is taking time" - do you understand what that multiplication parameter is actually doing? It's a timeout and waiting that long (in milliseconds) for messages. Also, Kafka consumers should generally run indefinitely, anyway